# How to apply the Green's Theorem in this case

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the region S bounded between the square with corners at the points (4,4),(-4,4),(-4,-4) and (4,-4) (oriented counterclockwise), and the circle of radius 2 centered at the origin (oriented clockwise.) Consider F(x,y)=($\frac{-y}{(x+1)^2+4y^2}$,$\frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2+4y^2}$) and calculate $\int_{dS}$F dA.

But then I found out $\frac{dF2}{dx1}$=$\frac{dF1}{dx2}$,so how can I apply the Green's theorem?

Comment: @Maesumi, I'm pretty sure that the OP is asking about a line integral, in which case this should indeed be taken over the boundary of $S$. It is true that this should not be denoted using $dA$ however.

Comment: I think that for him $dA$ is $(dx,dy)$ and $F.dA=F_1dx+F_2dy$ ...